# Transform image from BGR to sRGB in Numpy/OpenCV

Tags: python, numpy, opencv

Given a numpy array of dimensions (width, height, 3) in BGR format, how can I transform this image into sRGB space? OpenCV (`cv2`) does not implement this transformation, nor any transformation to sRGB for that matter.

I have conducted some research and could not find any function that does this, or even a formula that I can follow to implement my own function.

Any suggestion or guidance? And why is this transformation such an obscure thing on the internet?

Comment: I suspect that BGR format is already sRGB with the channels reversed. OpenCV reads an input sRGB image into BGR format, but does not linearize the channels. The data is read as is, but the channels are swapped. When it writes an image out, it is then again in sRGB format. However, if the input is linear RGB, then I suspect it would not change that and you would have to convert to non-linear sRGB. That could be done with profiles.

Comment: @fmw42 if the pixel values are linear, you'll know because they'll be larger than 8 bits per channel.  And the conversion between linear and sRGB is easy to find, starting with Wikipedia.

Comment: Linear does not mean that you have more than 8-bits. Linear RGB will just be darker than sRGB

Comment: @fmw42 you're right, linear does not automatically mean more than 8 bits.  But as a practical matter a linear image with 8 bits or less won't be very usable, the quality will be too poor.  So you're unlikely to run into one.

Comment: Linear RGB is often used for certain kinds of processing such as resizing in order to avoid some kinds of subtle artifacts. But one starts with sRGB, converts to linear RGB, do the processing, then convert back to sRGB. It is not poor quality. It is just darker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BGR format is already sRGB with the channels reversed. OpenCV reads an input sRGB image into BGR format, but does not linearize the channels. The data is read as is, but the channels are swapped. When it writes an image out, it is then again in sRGB format. However, if the input image is linear RGB, then I suspect OpenCV would not change that and you would have to convert to non-linear sRGB, if you wanted that as output. As far as I know, OpenCV does not have a method of changing between non-linear and linear RGB in either direction. You might be able to do that with profiles in PIL.

Linear RGB is often used for certain kinds of processing such as resizing in order to avoid some kinds of subtle artifacts. But one starts with sRGB, converts to linear RGB, process the image, then converts back to sRGB. Linear does not mean or give poor quality. It is just darker.

Here is a non-linear sRGB image, which looks as expected:

[image]

Here is a linear RGB image, which is just darker:

[image]

The linear one comes from Imagemagick with the command:

```
convert lena.png -colorspace RGB lena_srgb.png
```

and the non-linear one is:

```
convert lena.png -colorspace sRGB lena_srgb.png
```

which does nothing to change the image, since it was already sRGB.

Most tools do not distinguish between RGB and sRGB. They often refer to sRGB as just RGB.

Comment: The linear RGB doesn't look any darker on my browser.  Are you sure imgur didn't do an additional conversion on it?  Also Imagemagick might be using floats on the linear RGB rather than 8-bit integers.

Comment: IMGUR must not recognize linear RGB and treats it like sRGB. Imagemagick always computes as doubles, but saves to the quantum range defined by the install. In my case the install was 16-bits. I did not tell it to make the bit depth down to 8-bits. So both images are equivalent in bit-depth. Try a different viewer such as your browser.

Comment: You or IMGUR must be doing something odd. If I use Imagemagick compare to get an rmse difference, it show: 1compare -metric rmse lena_rgb.png lena_srgb.png null:
15372.7 (0.234573)`, which is a very large difference.

Comment: Thank you @fmw42! It seems to me that my problem was due to a misunderstanding of the concepts. Now it makes more sense! :)